# can't get Will_Paginate to work on my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, will-paginate

I can't get will_paginate to work on a pinterest style rails app I am creating. I have been following the will_paginate railscast. 
I get an error from this line:
EDIT: This is the error I am getting:

```
NoMethodError in PinsController#index

undefined method `page' for "created_at desc":String
Rails.root: /Users etc....

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

What I did so far, I added will_paginate to my gemfile and ran bundle so:

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'jquery-rails
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'will_paginate', '> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end 

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end
```

This is my pins_controller.rb (where I get my error) :

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
# GET /pins
# GET /pins.json
def index
@pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pins }
end
end
```

This is my index.html.erb :

```
<%= render 'pages/home' %>
<div id="pins">
<%= render @pins %>
<%= will_paginate @pins %>
</div>
```

If you want to see what I have been doing before I started playing with will_paginate, you can see my code on [my github repo.](https://github.com/PistachioPony/ponies) I am new to posting questions but I have not found anything by searching here, and have tried to follow best practices. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I just edited this post so you can see it. Thx for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry did you try without the "order" clause ?

if it works without it can you try this :

```
@pins = Pin.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
```

Also, I saw in your gem file

gem 'will_paginate', '> 3.0'

I'm not sure the notation '> 3.0' is right ;  '~> 3.0' seems better.

If all of that does not solve your problem, try to run "bundle install" once again... maybe a problem with the bundler... and restart your server (EDIT from your comment)

Let us know if you find something !

Cheers,

Comment: I thought the >3.0 was weird but I was following how Ryan Bates did it in his railscast.It seems to work fine. His updated will_paginate video states that will_paginate 3.0 and up allow a .page so:     '.page(params[:page]).per_page(20)' also works. I tried both your answers and the .page version and all three worked. Please edit your answer so it includes to restart my server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after `order`:

```
Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

It's important.  With the space `("created_at desc").page...` gets evaluated and then passed to `order`...

Comment: Not it, that must have been a typo when I was creating the question. I do not have a space between order and the parenthesis. I fixed it so it won't confuse. Thx for looking tho!

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the way you call will_paginate in your controller, it should be

```
@pins = Pin.order('created_at desc').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

instead of

```
@pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

see https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: didn't work - same error: undefined method paginate (same but with 'paginate' instead of 'page'. Thanks so much for trying to help!